# Error trying to Create Enum

Tags: java, enums

With the following code:

```
package com.Flaiva.NEWMETHODS;
import java.lang.Enum;


public class Imgreel {
```

//*right here*//

```
    public Enum Mobtype{

    }
```

//*End*//

```
public void select(){

    }
}
```

I of course, tried to initialize an Enum as directly indicated by oracle java tutorials.Unfortunately its not working so could someone please clarify this for me...... before i die of insanity.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What isn't working exactly?

Comment: The keyword is `enum`, lower case.

Comment: At least give us the error.

Comment: oh... the error.. sorry brb

Comment: ohk guys... dont worry

Comment: i change the java building version and it stopped... so idk what the error is anymore...but i swear... it was giving me syntax and telling me to import the java.lang.Enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enum is keyword and every keyword in java starts with lower case

change your code to

```
package com.Flaiva.NEWMETHODS;
import java.lang.Enum;


public class Imgreel {


    public enum Mobtype{

    }


public void select(){

    }
}
```

Comment: but it gives me syntax

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer what do you mean by it gives me syntax?

Comment: but thats all dont with now...i have a new problem.... my .jar file simpkly wont run... it doesnt even give me an error, and even in eclipse only some run(none of them have any errors to be fixed).

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer if you have new problem then post another question. If your current problem is solved then you can accept this answer

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer you can mail me your problem

Answer (score 0):

No need to import Enum

Also change Enum to enum in the public Enum Mobtype
Change it to, `public enum Mobtype {`

Comment: i literally copied an enum from oracle tutorials and got 5 syntax errors

Comment: Do what I have said and tell me if anything else is wrong. This will be creating an inner class enum as your first code was attempting to do. If you want the class to do it then replace class with enum. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html Look at the first example.